# Where do I find stock photography I can use on a Shopify theme?

Tags: product-photography, stock-photography, creative-commons

I am working on a theme for Shopify, but they require that you provide some stock images inside your theme to demonstrate how your theme would work in a 'realistic' context.

The types of images that I'm looking for are product shots, and I need a set of images. For sake of continuity in design, they should all be taken within a similar context or style.

Is there such a resource?

Comment: So is this question really "where can I buy stock photography?"?

Comment: Depends, there are specific criteria that I'm looking for. So no, not necessarily, If there are free alternatives like Creative Commons licences, that's fine too, the main criteria is that it fits in as a set of 20 or so same style product shots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using any stock site which provides galleries by the same photographer.

For example, ShutterStock and iStockPhoto allow you to browse other images by photographer. Just search for a single product shot, and then look at the photographer's portfolio for similar shots.

Alternatively, check the collections features which allow photographers and customers to collate similar images.